# I want to pass predicate parameter to generic repository GetAll method in C# Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, repository-pattern

I want to filter my GetAll Repository function by passing predicate. I want to place a check that if country is not coming from ajax request, it should not be filtered and bring all records.
What i was wanting, see image
[image]

**How i resolved it**
I have resolved this problem by writing my own code, but i doubt it will be slower as it will first bring all the records. What is the perfect way, i am still confused.

```
string country = Request["country"]+"";


           ICollection<Location> set = new LocationRepository().GetAll().ToList<Location>();

           if (country != "")
               set = set.Where(p => p.Country == country).ToList();

           List<Location> list =  set.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Id).Take(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will be something like the following

```
public void GetAll(Expression<Func<Location, bool>> exp)
{
....
}
```